# Google custom search api does not deliver any pictures

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, google-api, google-api-client, google-custom-search

I am using API Client Library for .NET this is how my google page looks:

[image]

I got a few problems

1. I see only a few results compared to a normal google search without the API usage
2. I don't know how to show only IMAGES as the result

The code snippet that I used [came from this page](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/google-search-in-c-a-step-by-step-walk-through-tutorial/)

Comment: Code snippet I use: https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/google-search-in-c-a-step-by-step-walk-through-tutorial/